# How to install github package within a R session using system("")?

Tags: r

I would like to install a package from within a R session from my personal repo on git. Basically:

`devtools::install_github('me/somepackage')`

works fine. However Im struggling to find the right syntax to install that package within an running R session on ubuntu. What I tried was:

`system("sudo su - -c "R -e \"devtools::install_github('me/somepackage')\""")`

for installtion into global library.

which returns `Error: unexpected symbol in "system("sudo su - -c "R"`

Since `sudo su - -c "R -e \"devtools::install_github('me/somepackage')\""`

works fine I assumed that it will not causing an error.

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: perhaps `"sudo su - -c \"R -e \\\"devtools::install_github('me/somepackage')\\\"\""`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `lobstr` package as an example, this format works for me:
`sudo su - -c "R -e \"devtools::install_github('r-lib/lobstr')\""`

To confirm, in terminal run:
`R`
`library(lobstr)`
`devtools::session_info()$packages["lobstr", "source"]`

```
[1] "Github (r-lib/lobstr@aedfeb8)"
```

You can also use `installed.packages()` and `.libPaths()` to make sure it was installed in the expected location.